# How to show timepickerdialog with 12h AM/PM

Tags: java, android, timepicker

I'm learning Android so I made an "app" but when the app open the timepickerdialog it shows a 24h clock. I need to show 12h AM/PM.

I read that I need to use the is24HourView, but I dont know how and where. Can you show me where? Here is part of the code.

```
    private void setDateTimeField() {
    theHour.setOnClickListener(this);

    Calendar newCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    theHourPickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(this, new OnTimeSetListener() {
        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
            Calendar theTime = Calendar.getInstance();
            theTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
            theTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
            theHour.setText(timeFormatter.format(theTime.getTime()));
        }
    }, newCalendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), newCalendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE),true);
}
```

I tried to put theHourPickerDialog.is24HourView(false) but it did not work XD

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, I found the problem (really silly), the last line must have false not true. `newCalendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), newCalendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE),false);`

Answer (score 0):

Notice that you should call setIs24HourView(false) before you set time on here.